# C++/CLI Finalizers and Operators

Tags: .net, c++-cli, managed-c++

In the following example, I get:

```
error C2300: 'UnmanagedClass' : class does not have a finalizer called '!SmartPointer'
```

If I remove the operator->, this error goes away.  Could someone explain why this is happening?

```
// Unmanaged class.
class UnmanagedClass { };

public ref class SmartPointer {
public:
    SmartPointer(UnmanagedClass* u) : m_ptr(u) { }
    ~SmartPointer() { this->!SmartPointer(); }
    !SmartPointer() { delete m_ptr; }

    // This line triggers C2300.
    UnmanagedClass* operator->() { return m_ptr; }
};

int main() {
    SmartPointer^ s = gcnew SmartPointer(new UnmanagedClass);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overriding the -> operator, so when you do:

```
~SmartPointer() { this->!SmartPointer(); }
```

You're effectively calling

```
~SmartPointer() { m_ptr->!SmartPointer(); }
```

I believe you can work around this by doing this, though:

```
~SmartPointer() { (*this).!SmartPointer(); }
```

Comment: That makes sense Reed, thank you; can't believe I didn't realize that.  Unfortunately I have operator* overloaded as well.  Just doing

    ~SmartPointer() { !SmartPointer(); }

doesn't work either.

Comment: Got it: 


~SmartPointer() { SmartPointer::!SmartPointer(); }


Thanks again.  Ryan